# ProtonMail bridge installation for a newbie

Tags: command-line, thunderbird, 18.10, gnupg, ownership

Just installed Ubuntu 18.10 two weeks a go and it's my first Linux distro.
Everything's working fine and I want to start playing with the terminal.

So I want to **install** this still in beta **ProtonMail bridge** for Thunderbird and the instructions are asking me to copy this :

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07
sudo gpg --dearmor --output /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07/debsig.gpg bridge_pubkey.gpg
```

**Problem** is that I always get this response :

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/ulfberht/.gnupg'
gpg: can't open 'bridge_pubkey.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: dearmoring failed: No such file or directory
```

Other information that might help you understand my problem, **I tried** :

`ls /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/`    and it gives me "`E2C75D68E6234B07`" correctly

I have installed debsig

bridge_pubkey.gpg is a document I have in my documents folder

As a sign of gratitude, here's the latest links to the linux bridge :

Deb:  https://protonmail.com/download/protonmail-bridge_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
RPM: https://protonmail.com/download/protonmail-bridge-1.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think the format of your key-fetching string is right.  Is there *anything* in `/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07`?  (`ls /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07` will tell us)

Comment: Terminal doesn't do anything when I copy `ls /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07`

Comment: Ok, from where do you execute those commands? If it is not from the directory where bridge_pubkey.gpg is located, it will not find it like that.

Comment: Ok I think you helped me find the problem. I have the document in my /home/ulfberht/Documents/ProtonMail/bridge_pubkey.gpg. I will try to use this instead

Comment: Tried : `sudo gpg --dearmor --output /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07/debsig.gpg /home/ulfberht/Documents/ProtonMail/bridge_pubkey.gpg`
`gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/ulfberht/.gnupg'
File '/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/E2C75D68E6234B07/debsig.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N)`

Comment: And what happens if you select "y"? The only one interacting with that directory is you, there is no harm overwriting that file which is probably empty and got created during one of your earlier attempts.

Comment: Nothing, the terminal just brings me at the start of another command line starting with $. I also tried with "N" and than chose a new name to rename the file but the name of my file didn't change in my documents

Comment: Well then you're good to go. Continue the instructions from the ProtonMail Bridge package.

Comment: By the way, unless you suspect that someone tampered with the files you downloaded, all this is unnecessary to install the application. It only serves to verify that the content is what it's supposed to be. The only command necessary to actually install it is the "sudo apt-get install" line at the end of the instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot M. Sebastian. Forgot all about the instructions and went right to `sudo apt-get install ./protonmail-bridge_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb` **Works just fine!** Still don't really understand how to verify my content but since my bridge is now installed, **case close!**